# get value in mysql LIKE query

Tags: mysql

My problem seems to be simple,but i m not getting logic despite of trying from so many long hours,please help me

**PROBLEM:**I am writing mysql stored procedure where i have LIKE statements in WHERE clause,i want to pass value in LIKE clause from IN parameter.

Although query executed but returning 0 rows.

MY STORED PROCEDURE

```
CREATE DEFINER=`****`@`%` PROCEDURE `GET_FEE_DAY_REPORT`(
IN p_center varchar(150),
  IN p_FId varchar(150),
  IN p_cId varchar(150)
  )
BEGIN
set  p_center=(select concat("'",p_center,"%","'") );
set p_FId=(select concat("'",p_FId,"%","'") );
set p_cId=(select concat("'",p_cId,"%","'") );

                    Select
                    SD.Application_No as 'Application No',
                    SD.S_Name as 'Stud Name',
                    IFNULL((Select Sum(fpd_fees_paid_amount) from fees_paid_details where fpd_stu_id=SD.S_Id),0) as Fees_paid,
                    fpd_fees_paid_date as 'Paid On',
                    fpd_cheque_no as 'Check Number',
                    case when fpd_tran_mode=1 then "CASH" when fpd_tran_mode=2 then "CHEQUE" end as 'Paid Mode',
                    (select Employee_Name from users where USER_ID=fpd_created_by) as 'Collected By'
                From
                    student_details SD LEFT JOIN fees_paid_details FPD ON SD.S_Id=fpd_stu_id,
                    fees_collect_category FCC       
                where
                    SD.F_Id=FCC.F_Id
                    and SD.C_Id=FCC.C_id
                    AND SD.F_Id LIKE p_FId
                    AND SD.C_id LIKE p_cId
                    AND SD.Centre_Id LIKE p_center
                    AND SD.Dropouts=0
                    order by SD.Centre_Id,SD.F_id,SD.C_id;
END
```

when i execute only query out of procedure it writes 518 rows for same parameter values

```
Select
                    SD.Application_No as 'Application No',
                    SD.S_Name as 'Stud Name',
                    IFNULL((Select Sum(fpd_fees_paid_amount) from fees_paid_details where fpd_stu_id=SD.S_Id),0) as Fees_paid,
                    fpd_fees_paid_date as 'Paid On',
                    fpd_cheque_no as 'Check Number',
                    case when fpd_tran_mode=1 then "CASH" when fpd_tran_mode=2 then "CHEQUE" end as 'Paid Mode',
                    (select Employee_Name from users where USER_ID=fpd_created_by) as 'Collected By'
                From
                    student_details SD LEFT JOIN fees_paid_details FPD ON SD.S_Id=fpd_stu_id,
                    fees_collect_category FCC       
                where
                    SD.F_Id=FCC.F_Id
                    and SD.C_Id=FCC.C_id
                    AND SD.F_Id LIKE '%%'
                    AND SD.C_id LIKE '%%'
                    AND SD.Centre_Id LIKE '1%'
                    AND SD.Dropouts=0
                    order by SD.Centre_Id,SD.F_id,SD.C_id;
```

**EDIT**
just observe the things here

```
set p_center= concat("'",p_center,"%","'");
set p_FId= concat("'",p_FId,"%","'");
set p_cId= concat("'",p_cId,"%","'");

select p_center,p_FId,p_cId;
```

this will returen OUTPUT as

```
p_center, p_FId,   p_cId
'1%',       '%',    '%'
```

so when i pass it to where clause it seems,it is not taking those value

Comment: Add sample data and expected result for an **MCVE**

Comment: @GuruV i dint got your point.I just need to know how to include INPUT parameter to LIKE statement

Comment: somebody please tell the solution if it exists....if not then please suggest alternate solution instead of downvoting

Comment: Try losing the single quotes in your set statements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given

```
MariaDB [sandbox]> select * from product;
+----+-------------------------------------+---------+------------+------------+
| id | title                               | InStock | qtyperunit | qtyonorder |
+----+-------------------------------------+---------+------------+------------+
|  1 | Product (color:green => size:S)     |      10 |          1 |          2 |
|  2 | Product (color:green,red => size:S) |      10 |          1 |          2 |
|  3 | Product (color:red)                 |      10 |          1 |          2 |
+----+-------------------------------------+---------+------------+------------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

This procedure (note how the variable ptitle is set)

```
drop procedure if exists p;

    delimiter //

    CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `p`(
        IN `instring` varchar(255)
    )
    LANGUAGE SQL
    NOT DETERMINISTIC
    CONTAINS SQL
    SQL SECURITY DEFINER
    COMMENT ''
    begin

    drop table if exists occursresults;
    create table occursresults (col1 varchar(20), col2 varchar(50));
    set @Ptitle = concat(instring,'%');

    insert into occursresults(col1,col2)
    select id, title
    from    product where title like @ptitle;

    end //

    delimiter ;
```

Returns

```
MariaDB [sandbox]> call p('Product (color:green');
Query OK, 2 rows affected (0.35 sec)

MariaDB [sandbox]> select * from occursresults;
+------+-------------------------------------+
| col1 | col2                                |
+------+-------------------------------------+
| 1    | Product (color:green => size:S)     |
| 2    | Product (color:green,red => size:S) |
+------+-------------------------------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: yes this is what need is `set @Ptitle = concat(instring,'%');`...Please help me understand this. Example i will give `IN p_FId varchar(150)`  as  `1`. 
                                                                                                           `AND SD.F_Id LIKE 'p_FId '` should be `AND SD.F_Id LIKE '1'` when i pass it into where clause.

Comment: Awesome .I analysed what was my mistake.Thank you so much @P.Salmon...`select * from Thankyou limit 1000;` ...;-)